# JavaFX 2, SWT and Webstart

Tags: java, swt, javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

We are developing an SWT application which uses some JavaFX controls. The example in 
   http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm
suggests we use the locally installed version of `jfxrt.jar` as the JavaFX runtime environment, and that NetBeans will use this jar as part of the package when building a webstart/jnlp distribution.

However, this is generally not encouraged because the jfxrt.jar has to match the installed version at the client (and will otherwise lead to a crash). Instead it is suggested to define a dependency to JavaFX in your jnlp file using the

```
<jfx:javafx-runtime [...]>
```

tag. Unfortunately, when doing so, the SWT integration fails by throwing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Canvas
```

This is likely because of the way the SWT classes are located.

Is there any way, this scenario is supported?

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: Try using [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) to build the project rather than NetBeans - it is likely more adept at building SWT+JavaFX apps than NetBeans.

Comment: @jewelsea: Thanks for this hint. Using the e(fx)clipse way (which actually uses the javafx ant task) to create a package produces a JAR file pointing to the SWT jar in the manifest file (using JavaFX-Class-Path). This allows starting the application standalone wihtout providing jfxrt (which is good), but still fails over webstart throwing the ClassNotFoundException (which is still bad).

Comment: The e(fx)clipse guys must have worked out a way to get JavaFX+SWT running in WebStart mode, try asking on their [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!forum/efxclipse).

Comment: Did you try with a signed WebStart app and see if that worked?

Comment: Yes, I did try. I will see, if I can get some help from the e(fx)clipse team. Thanks so far.

Comment: @Jens Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I assume, that it should work without bundled jxfrt.jar when using java 8, however I did not try so far. Actually we decided not to use webstart further.